# OpenLayers icon interaction: feature.get(...).getImage is not a function

Tags: openlayers, style, markers

I try to add a hover and click interaction to the points (displayed as marker icons) I show in my map. I want to display a border around the icon that is selected/hovered. I started by using the [OpenLayers example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon-negative.html) and found [a question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44738247/openlayers3-how-to-add-a-colored-border-around-a-marker-icon) covering exactly my concern. So I built my function based on those examples, but if I hover over a marker the console gives the error `feature.get(...).getImage is not a function`. I can't find any solution to my problem.

I use a switch statement to assign every point in my map a specific SVG-icon (standard style, without interaction):

```
function stylePoint(feature, resolution) {
switch(feature.get('type')) {
case '1':
    icon = '.../1.svg';
    break;
case '2':
    icon = '.../.2svg';
    break;
}
return [new ol.style.Style({
    text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: '10px bold Calibri',
        text: resolution < 40 ? feature.get('number') : '',
        offsetX: 10,
        offsetY: -15,
        textAlign: 'top',
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgb(0,0,0)'}),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'rgb(255,255,255)', width: 2.5})
    }),
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
        src: icon,
        scale: 0.025
        })
    })
];
};
```

So this works perfectly as intended. I then added the interaction:

```
var selectClick = new ol.interaction.Select({
  condition: ol.events.condition.click,
  layers: [point],
  style: highlightPoint
});
var selectHover = new ol.interaction.Select({
  condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove,
  layers: [point],
  style: highlightPoint
});
map.addInteraction(selectClick);
map.addInteraction(selectHover);
```

The interaction refers to another style function (the one that should apply on hover and click):

```
function highlightPoint(feature, resolution) {
switch(feature.get('type')) {
case '1':
    icon = '.../1.svg';
    break;
case '2':
    icon = '.../2.svg';
    break;

feature.set('style', stylePoint);

var image = feature.get('style').getImage().getImage();
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var activeColor = "red"; //set border color
var dArr = [-1,-1, 0,-1, 1,-1, -1,0, 1,0, -1,1, 0,1, 1,1], // offset array
    s = 2,  // thickness scale
    i = 0,  // iterator
    x = 2,  // final x position
    y = 2;  // final y position

//set new canvas dimentions adjusted for border
canvas.width = image.width + s + s;
canvas.height = image.height + s + s;

// draw images at offsets from the array scaled by s
for(; i < dArr.length; i += 2)
ctx.drawImage(image, x + dArr[i]*s, y + dArr[i+1]*s);

// fill with color
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
ctx.fillStyle = activeColor;
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

// draw original image in normal mode
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
ctx.drawImage(image, x, y,image.width, image.height);

return [new ol.style.Style({
    text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: '10px bold Calibri',
        text: resolution < 40 ? feature.get('number') : '',
        offsetX: 10,
        offsetY: -15,
        textAlign: 'top',
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'rgb(0,0,0)'}),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'rgb(255,255,255)', width: 2.5})
    }),
    image: new ol.style.Icon({
        src: icon,
        scale: 0.025,
        img: canvas,
        imgSize: canvas ? [canvas.width, canvas.height] : undefined
    })
}),
];
};
```

So most of the code is basically copy + paste from the StackOverflow question. But I already get stuck in the line `var image = feature.get('style').getImage().getImage();` and I don't understand why. The keyword `style` refers to my style function. And if I print `feature.set('style', stylePoint);` in the console I get the style function `stylePoint` (as it should be I think).

I use OpenLayers 6.5.0.

Comment: You have a function which returns an array, the function does not have a getImage() method, you need to call the function and use an element from the array `var image = feature.get('style')(feature)[0].getImage().getImage();`

Comment: @Mike what does the array contain? Every style for every feature my layer contains? If I add the code as you suggested I get the OpenLayers error 4 `image and src cannot be provided at the same time.`. I actually don't really know what to do now. I tried to find information on the error and how to solve it, but I got nothing useful.

Comment: The array contains the return from `stylePoint` for the feature. You do not need `icon` in function `highlightPoint` since you are using the canvas.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the problem! If you answer the question I will mark it as solved.